# FFI: How to declare `size_t`

Tags: haskell, ffi

I am trying to compile an example from Real World Haskell (chapter 26):

There is a `C` function I want to call using `FFI`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

/* only accepts uint32_t aligned arrays of uint32_t */
void hashword2(const uint32_t *key,  /* array of uint32_t */
           size_t length,        /* number of uint32_t values */
           uint32_t *pc,         /* in: seed1, out: hash1 */
           uint32_t *pb);        /* in: seed2, out: hash2 */
```

Here's the haskell code that tries to import it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Data.Word (Word32, Word64)
import Foreign.C.Types (CSize)
import Foreign.Marshal.Utils (with)
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr, castPtr, plusPtr)
import Foreign.Storable (Storable, peek, sizeOf)

foreign import ccall unsafe "lookup3.h hashword2" hashWord2
    :: Ptr Word32 -> CSize -> Ptr Word32 -> Ptr Word32 -> IO ()
```

When I try to compile it `ghc` gives the following error message:

```
Unacceptable argument type in foreign declaration: CSize
When checking declaration:
  foreign import ccall unsafe "static lookup3.h hashword2" hashWord2
    :: Ptr Word32 -> CSize -> Ptr Word32 -> Ptr Word32 -> IO ()
```

What type should I use to marshal a `size_t`? If I replace `CSize` and use `Word64` instead it will compile, but `Word64` is not portable, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you imported `CSize` as an abstract type. The FFI allows newtype-wrapped versions of types such as `Word64`, but only if it can actually see the contained types.

In your case, changing the appropriate import line to

```
import Foreign.C.Types (CSize(..))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: And 7.10.1 gives a better error message: "Unacceptable argument type in foreign declaration:
      ‘CSize’ cannot be marshalled in a foreign call
        because its data construtor is not in scope
        Possible fix: import the data constructor to bring it into scope"